# Synology NAS upgrade to DSM 7.2-64570 Update 1 broke autoindexing in nginx Web Station

Tags: nginx, synology, nas

I'm far from experienced in any of this stuff so bear with me.

I Recently upgraded my DS1821+ to DSM 7.2-64570 Update 1. And a bunch of stuff went wonky.

Most of the stuff was just really irritating but is now mostly working again.
One thing I can seem to figure out is how to get **autoindexing** back on for one of the sites/portals in web station.

Before the upgrade I was able to add a file **user.conf** containing "**autoindex on;**" to **/usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/GUID_OF_SOME_KIND_SPECIFYING_THE_WEB_PORTAL/**
and the contents of the folder the web portal was pointed at could be viewed and downloaded via web browser.
I was able to identify which GUID directory to add it in because I could create the portal in web station and see that a new directory was created, therefore knowing that one was associated with the one I just created.

Now there are several other directories in /usr/local/etc/nginx/
besides conf.d that werent there before.

conf.d  conf.d-available  sites-available  sites-enabled

And each of these directories is fill of all kinds of files that seem to be recreated at each reboot so I cant figure out what is what.

**Any one know where/if I can put that config, or how I can otherwise turn on autoindexing?**

Thanks for any help!